# Using jQuery UI to style a div

Tags: jquery-ui

I have the jQuery UI "smoothness" theme and I would like to use the "look" to style divs on my page.  E.g. apply the gray, shaded, rounded-corner effect to a regular div that *ISN'T* an accordion, button, etc.

I thought it would be easy! Perhaps it is?!

Thanks!

Comment: just look in the style sheet and use the same classes for your divs that are referenced in the style sheet. Shouldn't be difficult at all with a little tinkering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery UI themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). You can select an existing theme or customize one, then using Chrome or Firefox/Firebug, for example, *Right-click* → *Inspect element* and copy the class names.

`ui-widget`, `ui-widget-content` and `ui-corner-all` are the most likely class names you will be looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I came up with need some CSS tweaking, but should work.

```
<div id="login" align="center" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<ul id="login_header" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    Header
</ul>
<div id="login_form" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    content
</div>
```